# Distributions that being to domain of attraction of a stable law that are not unimodal?

Tags: convergence, heavy-tailed, stable-distribution

I was wondering whether there are any distribution that belongs to the domain of attraction of a stable law that is not unimodal. It is known that distribution in that law converge to a stable distribution which are unimodal. If you may help me list distributions that belong to that law that they are not themselves stably distributed would be nice.

Comment: The three-hundred-year-old answer is the Bernoulli$(1/2)$ distribution, which (by the Central Limit Theorem) lies in the domain of attraction of the Normal distribution.  This alone ought to indicate the hopelessness of producing a thorough answer to this question.

Comment: Great thank you.  I'm sorry i wasn't clear I'm asking about stable with alpha less than 2 not the normal

Comment: I hope you will be able to generalize from the simple example I gave: doesn't it show that adding a little bump on the distribution isn't going to change anything about the domain of attraction?  Bimodality or multimodality tell us extremely little about the limiting behavior of sums.

Comment: Thank you very much for this comment. I like your remark that bimodality or multi modality doesn't tell us much about the limiting behaviour of the sums. Do you have a reference in mind? It would really be appreciated

Comment: With Laplace's introduction of the characteristic function in 1785 (published in *Théorie analytique des probabilités,* 1812) to study sums of random variables, such phenomena became obvious.  I suspect there would be few or no references past that point.

Answer (score 1):

I am in debt for Professor John Nolan for answering this question via email.

There are no popular distributions that belong to the domain of attraction of stable law that is themselves not unimodal. However, one may construct a distribution such that it belongs to the domain of attraction of a stable law that is not unimodal.

It is well-known that a normalised sum of random variables that converge to a non-degenerate distribution belong to the domain of attraction of a stable law.

Gnedenkov and Doeblin (1940) have shown that this can only be the case when the tails converge in a particular fashion using the "regularly varying functions."

Therefore, one may construct a distribution that obeys the law of Gnedenkov and Doeblin (1940) but is not unimodal. For example, if f(x) is a pdf of a stable random variable then the mixture density (f(x)+f(x+1))/2 is heavy tailed and converge to a stable law but has two modes: the first being the original mode and another is the original mode shifted by 1.

Comment: Most of this is correct, but the example at the end is not necessarily so.  The standard Normal distribution once again offers itself as a counterexample: the mixture is in the domain of attraction of the Normal distribution but the mixture density is not unimodal.

Comment: Exactly.. that was an example that a  normalized sum of stable random variables​ with non unimodal distribution converge to a unimodal distribution